# How can I delete a message form a server via IMAP?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I have conected Thunderbird 13.0 to my Exchange server via IMAP protocol.

Now, when I delete email message from Thunderbird, it is removed from Thunderbird, but not from server. Is there a way to delete a message from server using Thunderbird?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thunderbird defaults to marking messages for deletion, the messages will eventually be deleted from the server but not immediately -  usually the messages won't be deleted until you exit. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Deleting_messages_in_IMAP_accounts explains the behavior in a little more detail. There are some benefits and drawbacks to this - the most important benefit being if you undo a deletion, the server still has the message, so it doesn't have to be transferred back to the server to restore it, and the most important drawback being that deletions take time to synchronize with other clients.